# Obtaining the reference and key in Custom Object Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to pass the reference of the dataSnapshot and key of each specific object into a custom 'Message' object.

I've tried using the key 'String key' within the Message.class but it appears to come back null.

Here is how my Message object currently is:

```
public class Message {

    private String key;
    private String sender_id;
    private String sender_username;
    private String receiver_username;
    private String receiver_id;
    private String chat_id;
    private String message;
    private Firebase ref;
    private double createdAt;
    private boolean read;

    public Message() {
        // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize messages
    }

    public String getKey() { return key; }
    public String getSender_id() { return sender_id; }
    public String getSender_username() { return sender_username; }
    public String getReceiver_username() { return receiver_username; }
    public String getReceiver_id() { return receiver_id; }
    public String getChat_id() { return chat_id; }
    public String getMessage() { return message; }
    public Firebase getRef() { return ref; }
    public double getCreatedAt() { return createdAt; }
    public boolean getRead() { return read; }

}
```

Any ideas, how I properly pass the dataSnapshot.getKey() String to the custom object? I don't see an example on the Firebase docs, and to be clear I'm using the "legacy Firebase", before they updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get a `Message` instance from a `DataSnapshot`, you are likely doing:

```
Message message = snapshot.getValue(Message.class)
```

Since this is starting from `getValue()`, the message will not contain the key of the `DataSnapshot`.

What you can do is set the key yourself after reading the `Message`:

```
Message message = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
message.setKey(snapshot.getKey());
```

You'll want to mark the `getKey()` as `@JsonIgnore` in that case, to ensure that Jackson tries to auto-populate or serialize it.

Comment: How to do that if I want to set the key for each object in a complex JSON tree?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding a static method to create the object from the `DataSnapshot`:

```
public static Message FromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot)
{
    Message msg = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
    msg.setKey(snapshot.getKey());

    return msg;
}
```