# Include object key as field in Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase object like this:

```
"aaa" : {
    "bbb" : "ccc",
    "ddd" : "eee"
}
```

and I want to parse it as a POJO, keeping its key (`aaa`) as one of the fields:

```
class A {
    private String key; // "aaa"
    private String bbb; // "ccc"
    private String ddd; // "eee"
}
```

Can I do this in a clean way with Firebase, or do I have to parse it in the usual way an then set the `key` field manually?

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ???
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860224/obtaining-the-reference-and-key-in-custom-object-firebase-android/38860386#38860386

Answer (score 0):

you can use `key=datasnapshot.getKey()` in your `onDataChange()` for that.