# Firebase ValueEventListener causing duplicate entries in the RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Since the `ValueEventListener` gets triggered every time the data in the `Firebase Database` updates, it is also called when a new upload is done while the `RecyclerView` is showing. The way I have it now causes duplicate entries when this happens, because the `Upload` objects *are already* in the `mUploads List`. And when an upload is done, the whole database gets queried again and all items added to the already existing `ArrayList` I don't know how to solve this. Should I create a new `Arraylist` every time the ValueEventListener is triggered or do I need a completely different callback?
Also the `ValueEventListener` interfers with my `mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved` call because the `ValueEventListener` gets triggered as soon as I delete something.

```
public class ImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ImageAdapter mAdapter;

private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private FirebaseStorage mStorage;

private List<Upload> mUploads;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_images);

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());

                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

            mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ImagesActivity.this);

            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDeleteClick(final int position) {
    Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
    final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();

    StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
    imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
            mUploads.remove(position);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

clear `mUploads` before adding data in `addValueEventListener` like below

```
 mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mUploads.clear(); //change here

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());

                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

            mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ImagesActivity.this);

            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will do it like this! Would you say this approach overall is acceptable or would it be better to not query the whole database everytime changes are made?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a `ValueEventListener` consider attaching a `ChildEventListener`. This type of listener gets triggered for the individual child nodes that are added, changed, or removed.

When you initially attach a `ChildEventListener` its `onChildAdded` will be called for each child that the listener matches. Then when you add a child node to the database later, the `onChildAdded` will be called again *with only the existing child*. This makes it super easy to update the UI, just add the new child to the adapter.

A `ChildEventListener` also has an `onChildChanged` event, which gets triggered when a specific child is *changed*. Here too, the method gets triggered with only the existing child, once again making it easy to update just that child in the adapter.

See [listen for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events) in the Firebase documentation for more on this type of listener.

Comment: better solution

Comment: Thank you, sounds like this is exactly what I need! What do you think about my setKey/getkey approach to save the key as a reference to the corresponding Firebase node? I am a beginner and wonder if this is the correct way to temporarily store the key. I don't have the key in the constructor of my Upload class.

Comment: That approach sounds common. Just be sure to mark the key as `JsonIgnore`, so that it doesn't get written to the database.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860224/obtaining-the-reference-and-key-in-custom-object-firebase-android

Comment: I found another answer of yours where you use the @Exclude anotation. What's the difference between them? Can I use either of them?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

clear arraylist `mUploads.clear()` before addValueEventListener like below

```
mUploads.clear();
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you say I should set the adapter outside of the ValueEventListener and then just call notifyDataSetChanged instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` and this will read the data once, if you want to refresh the data, you can call it again, for more info 
[Firebase - read data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once)

Comment: This really looks great. The only problem is, that this wont get triggered when a new upload was made. So when I upload something in activity 1 and then quickly go into the RecyclerView activity, the upload wont trigger an update of the adapter. Do I have to add an additional ChildEvenListener for this?

Comment: If you know when the data might be changed addListenerForSingleValueEvent() again and clear the list before, if you need always listen to Firebase database changes addValueEventListener() and clear the list or check for every item if the item exist, if not add the item to the list

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` so that the data will be fetched once and at the end add `addChildEventListener` and override `onChildAdded` so new add items will be fetched also , I think this better than clearing the list and re-inflating the recyclerview

checkout the code

```
mDatabaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
            upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());

            mUploads.add(upload);
        }

        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ImagesActivity.this);
        mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mDatabaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

        })
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok thank you! Do you think I also should create and set the adapter outside of the ValueEventListener and then simply call notifyDataSetChanged?